# retrieve php error messages on bootstrap modal form submitting with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, form-submit

I have a bootstrap form and i use jquery modal so i can open it on the same index.php window and when it is submitted the form should close and save data to database which it does on the other hand if there are error messages from formValidation.php file then it should show error messages instead of closing form.Now it does disappear even if there are errors and when i open it up again error messages are shown.I know there has been similar questions but i really cant make up solution for weeks from all sources i can get so i am a bit frustrated.Would appreciate help.Here is my code.

Here is my **form** from **index.php** file

```
<div class="container" id="register" style="display:none">
    <div class="row centered-form">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Banāns <small>Sia</small></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" class="ajax" method="post" action="index.php"> 
                        <?php include('classes/errors.php'); ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Vārds</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstName;?>" id="firstname" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Vārds">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Uzvārds</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastName;?>" id="lastname" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Uzvārds">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Lietotājvārds</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $userName;?>" id="username" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Lietotājvārds">

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>E-pasts</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="E-pasta adrese">

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Telefona numurs</label>
                            <input type="number" name="number" value="<?php echo $number;?>" id="number" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Telefona numurs">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Parole</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Parole">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Apstipriniet paroli</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Apstipriniet paroli">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
                        <span id="success_msg"></span>
                        <span id="error_msg"></span>
                        <p><a href="index.php" rel="modal:close">Aizvērt</a> ...</p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my **formValidation.php**

```
<?php
include('classes/config.php');
$firstName = $lastName = $userName = $email = $number = $password1 = $password2 = "" ;
$errors = array();

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["firstname"]);
    $lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["lastname"]);
    $userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["username"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email"]);
    $number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["number"]);
    $password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["password1"]);
    $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["password2"]);


    if (empty($firstName)) {
        array_push($errors, "Lūdzu ievadiet vārdu.");
    } else {
        $firstName = test_input($firstName);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zēūīāšžčķļņA-ZŅĒŪĪĀŠŽČĶĻŅ]*$/",$firstName)) {
            array_push($errors, "Lūdzu ievadiet tikai burtus.");
        }
    }

    if (empty($lastName)) {
        array_push($errors, "Lūdzu ievadiet uzvārdu.");
    } else {
        $lastName = test_input($lastName);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zēūīāšžčķļņA-ZŅĒŪĪĀŠŽČĶĻŅ]*$/",$lastName)) {
            array_push($errors, "Lūdzu ievadiet tikai burtus.");
        }
    }

    if (empty($userName)){
        array_push($errors, "Lūdzu ievadiet lietotājvārdu.");
    } else {
        $userName = test_input($userName);
        if(strlen($userName <= "6")){
            array_push($errors, "Lietotājvārdam jāsastāv no vismaz 6 burtiem un/vai cipariem.");
        }
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        array_push($errors,"Lūdzu ievadiet e-pasta adresi.");
    } else {
        $email = test_input($email);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            array_push($errors, "Lūdzu pārbaudiet e-pasta adresi.");
        }

    }

    if (empty($number)) {
        $number = "NULL";
    } else {
        $number = test_input($number);
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{8}$/", $number)) {
            array_push($errors, "Lūdzu ievadiet 8 ciparu numuru.");
        }
    }

    if(!empty($password1) && $password1 == $password2){
        $password1 = test_input($password1);
        $password2 = test_input($password2);
    } elseif ($password1 != $password2){
        array_push($errors, "Paroles nesakrīt.");
    } else {
        array_push($errors, "Lūdzu ievadiet paroli.");
    }


    if(count($errors) == 0){
        $password = md5($password1);
        $query = "INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, username, email, phonenumber, password)
                VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$userName', '$email', '$number', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $_SESSION["username"] = "$userName";
        $_SESSION["succes"] = "Apsveicu, tu esi pieslēdzies!";
        header("location: index.php");
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

and my error messages are looped trough in seperate **errors.php** file and are echoed in error class in **index.php**

```
<?php  if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>
    <div class="error">
        <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
            <p><?php echo $error ?></p>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
<?php  endif ?>
```

And finally **Ajax**
This submits the form and it closes even if there are error messages.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
    var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var number = $("#number").val();
    var password1 = $("#password1").val();
    var password2 = $("#password2").val();
    var submit = $("#submit").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "classes/formValidation.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname,
            username: username,
            email: email,
            number: number,
            password1: password1,
            password2: password2,
        },
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "success"){
                $("#register").hide();
                location.reload();
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

*And i have tried this*
If i open up console it retrieves all my form name attributes in an object.I have tried to change action to my formValidation.php or errors.php but it does not work.

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(){
    var bzz = $(this),
        url = bzz.attr('action'),
        method = bzz.attr('method'),
        data = {};

        bzz.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
            var bzz = $(this),
                name = bzz.attr('name'),
                value = bzz.val();

            data[name] = value;
            console.log(data);
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
   return false;
});
```